# How to send an event from a listadapter in one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

Let me start by showing the basic structure of my app:

```
                  MainActivity                    
                     |  |
         -------------  ------------                                  
         |                         |
   SearchFragment           WatchListFragment             
         |                         |                       
SearchListViewFragment   WatchListListViewFragment
         |                         |
   SearchAdapter             WatchListAdapter
```

Now I have a situation where a click on a button in the listview is handled in the SearchAdapter, and this needs to result in the ID of the clicked listitem being passed to the WatchListFragment so I can add that item to the ListView of WatchListListViewFragment...

Passing stuff directly from one fragment to another seems to be bad practice, so I thought I'd try interfaces instead, passing the ID from SearchAdapter -> SearchListViewFragment -> SearchFragment -> MainActivity -> WatchListFragment. Not quite knowing what I was doing I ended up with four interfaces that looked pretty much the same. That just didn't seem right to me. So now I'm thinking about trying one single interface that's implemented by all involved classes. But that doesn't feel quite right either...

Is there some standard way of doing this that I should be using? Is the "one-interface-for-all" a good idea? I tried reading up on interfaces to get an idea, and while I get the idea in simplified textbook-examples, this case is a whole other mess...

Comment: I ended up using a totally different solution all together. At first Iwas going to have my WatchListAdapter extend ArrayAdapter, but I realized that I could reuse almost all of the code from my SearchAdapter (which extends SimpleCursorAdapter) if I let them both extend a common subclass of SimpleCursorAdapter. So the button click in SearchAdapter causes the DB to add an entry to a watchlist_table in my database. The WatchListAdapter subscribes to a custom onChange-listener in my DB and gets notified when an insert/update/delete has been performed in watchlist_table. Hope that can help someone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution in this specific case would be the Mediator pattern. I've actually implemented it in another part of the same app as the original question related to. JustSoAmazing's answer above only get's the "message" from the SearchAdapter to the MainActivity, but not all the way to the intended receiver, which was WatchListFragment. Of course, one could always implement the interface in MainActivity in such a way that it forwards the message down to WatchListFragment. However, this solution is more general and can be used by any class that implements the AppMediatorInterface to send any message, making it very flexible.

First we define an interface that any class that wishes to subscribe to notifications must implement.

**AppMediatorInterface.java**

```
public interface AppMediatorInterface {

    public void onAppMediatorNotification(Object sender, Object data);

}
```

Second we define the actual mediator class, I've chosen to make it static to make it easily available anywhere in the application.

**AppMediator.java**

```
public class AppMediator{
    protected static List<AppMediatorInterface> observers = new ArrayList<AppMediatorInterface>();

    public static void addObserver(AppMediatorInterface observer){
                observers.add( observer );
    }

    public static void removeObserver(Object observer){
        int pos = observers.indexOf(observer);

        if( pos>-1 )
            observers.remove(pos);
    }

    public static void notifyObservers(Object sender, Object data){
        for( int i=0; i<observers.size(); i++ ){
            observers.get(i)).onAppMediatorNotification(sender, data);
        }
    }

}
```

Sending a notification:

**SearchAdapter.java**

```
AppMediator.notifyObservers( this, "Add-button clicked" );
```

Receiving a notification:

**WatchListFragment.java**

```
public class WatchListFragment extends Fragment implements AppMediatorInterface{

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);                
        AppMediator.addObserver(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        AppMediator.removeObserver(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    /* --- AppMediatorInterface --- */
    @Override
    public void onAppMediatorNotification(Object sender, Object data) {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. It really helped. @BadCash

Answer (score 0):

Having one interface is the way to go. Instead of implementing it in all involved classes though and passing the listener reference around, you can do the following when you're working with fragments.

Create a public, static interface in your SearchAdapter class and have your main activity implement it. Then, in your SearchListViewFragment class, set the callback as follows:

`mySearchAdapter.setIdListener(getActivity())`

Because the activity implements the interface and because the fragment has access to the activity, this is a perfectly valid statement. You will get a ClassCastException, however, if the Activity doesn't implement in the interface.

Alternatively, you can just have a series of getter methods that give you access to the search adapter from the main activity and will let you set the callback.

For example, in your MainActivity class: `getSearchFragment().getSearchListViewFragment().getSearchAdapter().setIdListener(this)`